# Rewrite datetimeindex for timeseries for new Pandas version

Tags: python, pandas

I am developing a Machine Learning Model to do some time series forecasting. I wrote a general function to create a time-series for my data. When I was writing this, the datetimeindex method in pandas used to take different parameters and my function was executing properly. There has been a change to this method and I am not sure how to rewrite  this datetimeindex method? Can someone please help?
Here is the full timeseries function I wrote:

```
def make_time_series(mean_power_df, years, freq='D', start_idx=4):
    '''Creates as many time series as there are complete years. This code
       accounts for the leap year, 2016.
      :param Daily_Price_mean: A dataframe of bitcoin weighted price, averaged by day.
          This dataframe should also be indexed by a datetime.
      :param years: A list of years to make time series out of, ex. ['2013', '2014'].
      :param freq: The frequency of data recording (D = daily)
      :param start_idx: The starting dataframe index of the first point in the first time series.
          The default, 16, points to '2013-01-01'. 
      :return: A list of pd.Series(), time series data.
      '''

    
# store time series
time_series = []

# store leap year in this dataset
leap = '2012'

# create time series for each year in years
for i in range(len(years)):

    year = years[i]
    if(year == leap):
        end_idx = start_idx+366
    else:
        end_idx = start_idx+365

    # create start and end datetimes
    t_start = year + '-01-01' # Jan 1st of each year = t_start
    t_end = year + '-12-31' # Dec 31st = t_end

    # get global consumption data
    data = mean_power_df[start_idx:end_idx]

    # create time series for the year
    index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=t_start, end=t_end, freq=freq) ## this is the line causing problems, this was based on previous method inputs
    
    time_series.append(pd.Series(data=data, index=index))
    
    start_idx = end_idx

# return list of time series
return time_series
```

When I call this function  the following way:

```
group = data.groupby('date') #the data was read and processed...
Daily_Price_mean = group['Weighted_Price'].mean()
full_years = ['2012', '2013', '2014']
freq='D' # daily recordings
# make time series
time_series = make_time_series(Daily_Price_mean, full_years, freq=freq)
```

I get the error: TypeError: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start'

Can smeone please let me know how I can fix my function?
Thank you